# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input after call to Netlify function

Tags: javascript

i'm using Netlify serverless functions.

when I run JSON.parse on the event.body response I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`

My client side code is as follows:

```
const items = [{ id: 'prod_LvqkrsI9O5F0xJ' }];

async function initialize() {
    const response = await fetch('/.netlify/functions/createPaymentIntent', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ items }),
    });
    console.log(response);
    const { clientSecret } = await response.json();
```

Server side code is as follows:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const items = await JSON.parse(event.body);
    console.log('items', items);
```

the console logs out

```
items { items: [ { id: 'prod_LvqkrsI9O5F0xJ' } ] }
...{"level":"error","message":"End - Error:"}
{"errorMessage":"Unexpected end of JSON input","errorType":"SyntaxError","level":"error",...
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing about the offensive JSON data ...

Comment: Thanks for looking at the code. If I log out event.body I get {"items":[{"id":"prod_LvqkrsI9O5F0xJ"}]} if that is any use?

Comment: You have to consult the netlify API docs then.

Comment: your server side handler doesn't have a closing `}`. nor does your initialise function

Comment: did you try to console log the body before parsing it? I believe it is JSON because you used right header